# Priskribante subjekton, ĉu "esti <adverbo>" aŭ "esti <adjektivo>"?

Tags: adjectives, adverbs

Take for instance a simple sentence like "I am right". Should this then technically be "mi estas prave" (or even "mi prave estas") instead of "mi estas prava"? Why do I ask? Because, to me, this seems like...

- "Mi estas prava."

  - ...I myself am what is right, because I am a god[dess] or something.
- "Mi estas prave."/"Mi prave estas."

  - ...I "am being" right, e.g. because of something I said.

Granted, one could also have said "mi pravas", but ignore that case for the sake of this question. "Prav{a,e}" is just an example word I used in this question, but is not strictly limited to such a case.

In contrast, and also to better illustrate my question, take another sentence such as "I am pretty". Now, to me, this *does* describe how I am (and indeed I am! =^=), and thus, in my opinion, would be in the adjective form, ĉu ne?

- "Mi estas bela."

  - I myself am what is pretty.
- "Mi estas bele."/"Mi bele estas."

  - I...uh...exist prettily?

[This answered question](https://esperanto.stackexchange.com/questions/1275/estas-bele-vs-estas-bela-or-beli) is close-ish to mine, but not quite. I already know that adverbs in Esperanto can describe verbs, adjectives, and subclauses (e.g. "Estas bele, ke la monadoj kune ŝajne harmonias"), but here I am not sure what actually *should be* the thing that is described (i.e. the subject "mi", or the "estas"), and thus whether the adjective or the adverb should be used.

Comment: Priskribante _sin_ mem ...

Comment: Just noticed that it doesn't actually have to be one self, either, but any such subject (e.g. "ri estas dika"). But yes, good catch.

Comment: You can change the title if it is not gramatically correct. Better not to expose new learners to wrong constructions. Maybe _"Priskriboj - ĉu ..."_ aŭ rekte _"Ĉu esti ..."_.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Adjectives say something about the subject and adverbs say something about the verb or and adjective but not about the subject.

So you would always say:

```
Mi estas prava (the usual form is: mi pravas)
Mi estas bela
Mi estas rapida
```

When would you use the adverb with *esti*? When it says something about an adjective or a verb (infinitive or participle):

```
Mi estas tute sola
Mi estas sufiĉe kovrita de la littuko
Estus amuze kaŝi lian porteblan
```

Here *tute/sufiĉe* add information to *sola/kovrita* not to you. *Amuze* says something about *kaŝi*.

Also sometimes when the verb does not take a subject (or it is not mentioned), for example, or when the infinitive follows:

```
Tie estas tre varme (estas varma vetero)
```

That's not an exhaustive list, you can also check [*esti* en PMEG](https://bertilow.com/pmeg/gramatiko/gravaj_verboj/esti.html). Tie troviĝas multaj ekzemploj kaj klarigoj.

Answer (score 4):

There are two things worth noticing here.

1. In Esperanto adjectives are used for describing [nominals](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nominal_(linguistics)) (nouns, pronouns and adjectives in case of Esperanto), to describe anything else adverbs are used. See [PMEG](https://bertilow.com/pmeg/gramatiko/e-vortoj/uzo.html).
2. The verb *esti* is so called [copula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Copula_(linguistics)), i.e. a word, that links the subject to a predicative.

These give

- *Mi estas bela* : *bela* describes the pronoun, which in this case is the subject, "I am beautiful"

Should you use an adverb

- *Mi estas bele* : *bele* describes something else than the pronoun, which in this case must be the verb, but "I am beautifully" or "My being is beautiful" is pretty much senseless

Comment: Thank you for pointing out. I corrected the term to nominals.

Comment: This is a good explanation. I just want to point out that, in this particular instance, _Mi estas bele_ could take the other meaning of _esti_ in the sense of _ekzisti_, and so could mean “I exist in a beautiful manner”. It is odd, but it does make sense. Just don't do that, unless you're being really poetic or literary.